# Loading tinymce dynamically

Tags: javascript, ajax, tinymce

When tinymce is in head, and loads before dom, all is ok. But if i'll try to load the javascript with ajax(`jquery.getScript()`) it does not work.
I'm initalizing tinymce when user clicks the content area, so dom must be ready then.
I'd like to get it working without altering tinymce code and not in head tag, cause the script is about 65kb(gzipped). My code looks like this:

```
window.tab_offers.show_edit = function() {
    if (init == true) {
        tinymce.execCommand('mceToggleEditor', false, 'offers-tab-content');
    } else {
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "exact",
            elements: "offers-tab-content",
            language : window.PAGE_LANG,
            theme : "advanced",
            content_css: site_url('css/parim/tinymce.css'),
            plugins : "autoresize",
            width: $('#offers-tab-content').width() + 18,
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "cancelforecolor,backcolor,separator,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,undo,redo,separator,hr,removeformat,separator,charmap,separator,link,unlink",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : ""
        });
    init = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: what happens if you set no plugins and no buttons at all, does it initialize? Where do you load the tiny_mce.js?

Comment: When i load tiny_mce.js on head(script tag), everething works but when i'll try to load tiny_mce.js with ajax(getScript()), tinymce loads nothing. Iguess it maybe have someting todo with dom ready. I'll try to trick tinymce that the dom is ready without an event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem. Tinymce tries to get "baseURL" from script tags, but if i'll load it dynamiclly, then there is no match. It iterates over every script element on page and check it like so: `/tiny_mce(|_gzip|_jquery|_prototype|_full)(_dev|_src)?.js/.test(n.src)`. So i  just overrided the baseURL parameter like so:
    tinyMCE.baseURL = "http://mysite.com/path_to_tinymce/";
    tinyMCE.init({ ..., ... });